# Support of union type in graphql

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I'm trying to do an api with nest.js and the @nestjs/graphql module.
I took the example boilerplate [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/examples/12-graphql-apollo) to start with.
I added/ updated this in the schema :

```html
type GraphQLError {
    message: String
    errorCode: Int
    type: String
}

union MutationResult = Cat | GraphQLError

type Mutation {
  createCat(name: String, age: Int): MutationResult
  deleteCat(id: ID): MutationResult
}
```

and I tried to defined the __resolveType function in class CatsResolvers :

```html
@Resolver('Cat')
export class CatsResolvers {
  constructor(private readonly catsService: CatsService) {}
  __resolveType(obj, context, info): string{
    return obj.errorCode ? 'GraphQLError' : 'Cat';
  }

  @Mutation('createCat')
  async create(obj, args: Cat, context, info): Promise<Cat | GraphQLError> {
    const createdCat = await this.catsService.create(args);
    pubsub.publish('catCreated', { catCreated: createdCat });
    return createdCat;
  }

}
```

I tried to insert a Cat with the following request :

```js
mutation insertCat {
  createCat(name:"kitty", age: 1) {
    ... on Cat {
      name
      age,
      id
    }
    ... on GraphQLError {
      errorCode
      message,
       type
    }
  }
}
```

and I have the error : 
Abstract type MutationResult must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Mutation.createCat with value \"[object Object]\", received \"undefined\". Either the MutationResult type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible types should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function.

I don't know what to do with this.
it seem's that resolveType is not implemented in @nestjs/graphql
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer for you concerning the nestjs framework and while I really love the "Either" approach known from functional programming using the union type, in practice we moved to a more extendable approach where `MutationResult` would be an object type with fields `success`, `errors` and `cat`. This has the benefit that this result could return more fields/objects.

Comment: Currently you only have CatsResolvers. You need to add a resolver for MutationResult which will check if your type is either Cat or GraphQLError.